# Jest/Enzyme Shallow testing RFC - not firing jest.fn()

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test the onChange prop (and the value) of an input on an RFC. On the tests, trying to simulate the event doesn't fire the jest mock function.

The actual component is connected (with redux) but I'm exporting it also as an unconnected component so I can do a shallow unit test. I'm also using some react-spring hooks for animation.

I've also tried to mount instead of shallow the component but I still get the same problem.

---

MY Component

```js
export const UnconnectedSearchInput: React.FC<INT.IInputProps> = ({ scrolled, getUserInputRequest }): JSX.Element => {

  const [change, setChange] = useState<string>('')


  const handleChange = (e: InputVal): void => {
    setChange(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleKeyUp = (): void => {
    getUserInputRequest(change)
  }

  return (
    <animated.div
      className="search-input"
      data-test="component-search-input"
      style={animateInputContainer}>

      <animated.input
        type="text"
        name="search"
        className="search-input__inp"
        data-test="search-input"
        style={animateInput}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onKeyUp={handleKeyUp}
        value={change}
      />
    </animated.div>
  )
}


export default connect(null, { getUserInputRequest })(UnconnectedSearchInput);
```

---

My Tests

Here you can see the test that is failing. Commented out code is other things that I-ve tried so far without any luck.

```
describe('test input and dispatch action', () => {
  let changeValueMock
  let wrapper
  const userInput = 'matrix'

  beforeEach(() => {
    changeValueMock = jest.fn()
    const props = {
      handleChange: changeValueMock
    }

    wrapper = shallow(<UnconnectedSearchInput {...props} />).dive()
    // wrapper = mount(<UnconnectedSearchInput {...props} />)
  })

  test('should update input value', () => {
    const input = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'search-input').dive()
    // const component = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'search-input').last()

    expect(input.name()).toBe('input')
    expect(changeValueMock).not.toHaveBeenCalled()

    input.props().onChange({ target: { value: userInput } }) // not geting called
    // input.simulate('change', { target: { value: userInput } })

    // used with mount
    // act(() => {
    //   input.props().onChange({ target: { value: userInput } })
    // })
    // wrapper.update()

    expect(changeValueMock).toBeCalledTimes(1)

    // expect(input.prop('value')).toBe(userInput);
  })
})
```

---

Test Error

Nothing too special here.

```
 expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledTimes(1)

    Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.

      71 |     // wrapper.update()
      72 | 
    > 73 |     expect(changeValueMock).toBeCalledTimes(1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated since it's been 2 days now and I cn't figure this out.

Comment: `getUserInputRequest` is called inside `handleKeyUp`, when you execute `input.props().onChange({ target: { value: userInput } })` it will call `handleChange`, not `handleKeyUp`

Comment: Yes that's right. Bad naming convention of the variable. Still doesn't affect the outcome since i actually want to test the `handleChange`. Will update to avoid any confusion. Thanks

Comment: in your test, you are passing a property `handleChange` to the component `UnconnectedSearchInput`. Note that `UnconnectedSearchInput` doesn't use the property `handleChange`, so it's normal that this property is never called

Comment: wait i'm confused. I'm passing the mock as `handleChange` to the `UnconnectedSearchInput` which is getting called on the `input` element on the `onChange={handleChange}` of the actual component. What am I missing here?

Comment: when you write `onChange={handleChange}`, it retrieves the `handleChange` function you declared just before `const handleChange = (e: InputVal): void => {
    setChange(e.target.value)
  }` not the one coming from the props

Comment: you cannot mock _internal variable_ declared inside of function(`handleChange` in your case).

Comment: @OlivierBoissé .. ok I see, it makes sense that the component will use the `handleChange` declared inside its body instead of the one passed as prop.

Comment: @skyboyer any workarounds fo this? I don't want to convert the component into a class component and use instance() to set the value directly. Plus i'd prefer to keep using hooks for those small tasks this component does

Comment: after executing `input.props().onChange({ target: { value: userInput } })`, you can check that the state variable `change` has correctly been set by checking the value of `input.props().value`, it should be equal to `userInput`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have to interact with component internals; instead better use public interface: props and render result

```
test('should update input value', () => {
  expect(findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'search-input').dive().props().value).toEqual('');
  findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'search-input').dive().props().onChange({ target: {value: '_test_'} });
  expect(findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'search-input').dive().props().value).toEqual('_test_');
}
```

See you don't need to check if some internal method has been called, what's its name or argument. If you get what you need - and you require to have `<input>` with some expected `value` - it does not matter how it happened.

But if function is passed from the outside(through `props`) you will definitely want to verify if it's called at some expected case

```
test('should call getUserInputRequest prop on keyUp event', () => {
  const getUserInputRequest = jest.fn();
  const mockedEvent = { target: { key: 'A' } };
  const = wrapper = shallow(<UnconnectedSearchInput getUserInputRequest={getUserInputRequest } />).dive()
  findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'search-input').dive().props().onKeyUp(mockedEvent)
  expect(getUserInputRequest).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(getUserInputRequest).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockedEvent);
}
```

[UPD] seems like caching selector in interm variable like

```
const input = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'search-input').dive();
input.props().onChange({ target: {value: '_test_'} });
expect(input.props().value).toEqual('_test_');
```

does not pass since `input` refers to stale old object where `value` does not update.

At enzyme's github I've [been answered](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2139#issuecomment-495947192) that it's expected behavior:

> This is intended behavior in enzyme v3 - see https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/migration-from-2-to-3.md#calling-props-after-a-state-change.
>
> So yes, exactly - everything must be re-found from the root if anything has changed.

Comment: Thanks for the example @skyboyer. Your first case for `should update input value` is in fact the very first thing i tried and it didn't work (just checked again just in case i missed something before). in-fact with the last assertion i get an empty string `Expected: "test" Received: "" `.

Comment: sorry, have no experience with react-test-renderer. try replacing `expect(input.props().value).toEqual('');` with `expect(findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'search-input').dive().props().value).toEqual('');`

Comment: or after line with  `...props().change(...)` you may try adding `await Promise.resolve()` in case react-test-renderer updates element in async way

Comment: but on the last assertion I guess i should actually expect a string not an empty string right?  :)  Anyway as a random thought I was thinking to split the component into container and presentational so I could pass the `handleChange` also as a prop

Comment: sorry, don't follow what do you mean. Also I've decided you use `react-test-renderer` because of `findByTestAttr` but tag says it's Enzyme. so what library do you use?

Comment: haha sorry I had to specify that. I use enzyme and `findByTestAttr` it's just a custom function that get `wrapper` and `value` and returns this `return wrapper.find(`[data-test="${val}"]`)`

Comment: yes, seems like `find(...)` points to outdate object after parent is updated; I've updated my asnwer, check it out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193932/discussion-between-skyboyer-and-grenos).